# Parse json through json_table in oracle 18

Tags: sql, json, oracle, parsing, oracle18c

There is a request for example:

```
with j (sJson) as (
   select '{
      "ID":"1444284517",
      "ID_ORD":"4255;2187606199",
      "Vals":{
               "CODE":"ONB2B3BB8",
               "DORD":"25.04.2021"
             }
   }'
   from dual
)

select jt.*
from j
cross apply json_table (j.sJson, '$'
   columns
      ID varchar2(32) path '$.ID',
      ID_ORD varchar2(32) path '$.ID_ORD',
        nested path '$.Vals[*]'
              columns (
                 CODE varchar2(9) path '$.CODE',
                 DORD varchar2(30) path '$.DORD',
                 ....
              )) jt
```

In `column` there may be different fields.
How to list all fields in `columns` without specifying the type and path? That is how to make it dynamic parser? Need to give up  `CODE varchar2(9) path '$.CODE'`
I expect this result:

```
| ID         | ID_ORD          | CODE      | DORD       |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+
| 1444284517 | 4255;2187606199 | ONB2B3BB8 | 25.04.2021 |
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the output you want from that example; and depending on what you mean by dynamic, a different example and its expected output.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I changed the question

Comment: There may be an indefinite number of fields in a Columns{ }

Comment: The number of output columns has to be known before the query is executed, so I don't think this is going to be possibly with static SQL. (It's conceptually similar to a pivot with an unknown number of columns.) Dynamic SQL would have to build the `columns` clause by parsing the JSON, which seems a bit painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the functions:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_keys(
  value IN CLOB
) RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST PIPELINED
IS
  js   JSON_OBJECT_T := JSON_OBJECT_T( value );
  keys JSON_KEY_LIST;
BEGIN
  keys := js.get_keys();
  FOR i in 1 .. keys.COUNT LOOP
    PIPE ROW ( keys(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/

CREATE FUNCTION get_value(
  value IN CLOB,
  path  IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  js JSON_OBJECT_T := JSON_OBJECT_T( value );
BEGIN
  RETURN js.get_string( path );
END;
/
```

Then use the query:

```sql
WITH j (sJson) as (
   select '{
      "ID":"1444284517",
      "ID_ORD":"4255;2187606199",
      "Vals":{
               "CODE":"ONB2B3BB8",
               "DORD":"25.04.2021"
             }
   }'
   from dual
)
SELECT jt.id,
       jt.id_ord,
       k.COLUMN_VALUE AS Key,
       get_value( jt.vals, k.COLUMN_VALUE ) AS value
FROM   j
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         j.sjson,
         '$'
         COLUMNS (
           id     VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.ID',
           id_ord VARCHAR2(30) PATH '$.ID_ORD',
           vals   VARCHAR2(4000) FORMAT JSON PATH '$.Vals'
         )
       ) jt
       CROSS APPLY get_keys( jt.vals ) k
```

Which outputs:

> | ID | ID_ORD | KEY | VALUE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1444284517 | 4255;2187606199 | CODE | ONB2B3BB8 |
> | 1444284517 | 4255;2187606199 | DORD | 25.04.2021 |

*(Note: SQL does not support a dynamic number of columns so you need to provide a fixed number of columns such as `key` and `value` and have the output as rows rather than columns.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d6df1f8f39deb43a8b73c86e935da4e2)*

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a variable number of columns then you will either need to do a dynamic pivot of a column-based result (such as from @MTO's answer), or generate a dynamic `json_table`.

You can use `json_dataguide()` to generate the schema for a specific `Vals` array, and then pass that through its own `json_table` and loop to generate the `columns` clause names, types and paths.

This example regenerates your original query, except it used a bind variable for the JSON string instead of a CTE; and then opens that using the same string that was used for the data guide.

```
create or replace function dynamic_parse(sJson clob)
return sys_refcursor as
  sGuide clob;
  sSQL clob;
  rc sys_refcursor;
begin
  -- initial static part of query
  sSQL := q'^select jt.*
from json_table (:sJson, '$'
   columns
      ID varchar2(32) path '$.ID',
      ID_ORD varchar2(32) path '$.ID_ORD',
        nested path '$.Vals[*]'
              columns (^';

  select json_dataguide(jt.vals)
  into sGuide
  from json_table (sJson, '$'
    columns
      VALS clob format json path '$.Vals'
  ) jt;

  for r in (
    select jt.*
    from json_table (sGuide format json, '$[*]'
      columns
        indx for ordinality,
        path varchar2(30) path '$."o:path"',
        type varchar2(30) path '$.type',
        length number path '$."o:length"'
    ) jt
  )
  loop
    sSQL := sSQL || case when r.indx > 1 then ',' end
      || chr(10) || '                 '
      || '"' || substr(r.path, 3) || '"'
      -- may need to handle other data type more carefully too
      || ' ' || case when r.type = 'string' then 'varchar2(' || r.length || ')' else r.type end
      || q'^ path '^' || r.path || q'^'^';
  end loop;

  -- final static part of query
  sSQL := sSQL || chr(10) || '              )) jt';
  dbms_output.put_line(sSQL);

  open rc for sSQL using sJson;
  return rc;
end;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a647e7d623a03fdaa1933809f3c27e25) showing some of the steps, the generated dynamic SQL statement, and how you could use that to open a ref cursor. The generated dynamic statement comes out as:

```
select jt.*
from json_table (:sJson, '$'
   columns
      ID varchar2(32) path '$.ID',
      ID_ORD varchar2(32) path '$.ID_ORD',
        nested path '$.Vals[*]'
              columns (
                 "CODE" varchar2(16) path '$.CODE',
                 "DORD" varchar2(16) path '$.DORD'
              )) jt
```

It also shows a dummy anonymous block that calls the function and prints the ref cursor contents (because db<>fiddle doesn't support `select func_returning_ref_cursor from dual` which you can do in SQL Developer etc.) as:

```
1444284517:4255;2187606199:ONB2B3BB8:25.04.2021
```

... but that demonstrates one of the problems with this approach: the caller has to know the number and types of columns in advance, or itself has to use some element of dynamic handling.

You may also want to explore the wider [JSON Data Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/json-dataguide.html#GUID-219FC30E-89A7-4189-BC36-7B961A24067C) functionality.

Answer (score 0):

SQL/JSON function json_table projects specific JSON data to columns of various SQL data types. You use it **to map parts of a JSON document** into the rows and columns of a new, virtual table, which you can also think of as an inline view.

Because your goal seems to be : Parse json through json_table. I suggest to read the JSON Data Guide feature.[here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adjsn/json-dataguide.html#GUID-219FC30E-89A7-4189-BC36-7B961A24067C). e;g You can create a view based on the structure of a row, the DBMS_JSON package will create the SQL/JSON for you. No need to code. You can also add virtual columns to your original table.

### Create a table with your document,

I added a new field XARR in order to show the power of JSON Data Guide feature

```
drop table test_json;

create table test_json
as
with j (sJson ) as (
   select CAST ('{
      "ID":"1444284517",
      "ID_ORD":"4255;2187606199",
      "Vals":{
               "CODE":"ONB2B3BB8",
               "DORD":"25.04.2021",
               "XARR":[{"IDARR":1},{"IDARR":2},{"IDARR":3}]
             }
   }' as VARCHAR2(2000))
   from dual
)
select *
from j;
```

### Create a view on top of your document,

```
SELECT json_dataguide(SJSON, DBMS_JSON.FORMAT_HIERARCHICAL, DBMS_JSON.PRETTY)
      FROM TEST_JSON;

drop view MYVIEW;
DECLARE
  dg CLOB;
  BEGIN
    SELECT json_dataguide(SJSON, DBMS_JSON.FORMAT_HIERARCHICAL, DBMS_JSON.PRETTY)
      INTO dg
      FROM TEST_JSON where rownum < 2;
    DBMS_JSON.create_view('MYVIEW',
                          'TEST_JSON',
                          'SJSON',
                          dg);
  END;
/
```

### Query the data

use directly the view or retrieve the SQL generated

```
select text from all_views where view_name =  'MYVIEW';      

TEXT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
-------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT RT."SJSON",JT."ID",JT."CODE",JT."DORD",JT."ID_ORD",JT."IDARR"
FROM "ADMIN"."TEST_JSON" RT,
JSON_TABLE("SJSON", '$[*]' COLUMNS 
"ID" varchar2(16) path '$.ID',
"CODE" varchar2(16) path '$.Vals.CODE',
"DORD" varchar2(16) path '$.Vals.DORD',
 NESTED PATH '$.Vals.XARR[*]' COLUMNS (
"IDARR" number path '$.IDARR'),
"ID_ORD" varchar2(16) path '$.ID_ORD')JT 

select * from myview;

ID         CODE      DORD       ID_ORD          IDARR 
---------- --------- ---------- --------------- --- 
1444284517 ONB2B3BB8 25.04.2021 4255;2187606199   1 
1444284517 ONB2B3BB8 25.04.2021 4255;2187606199   2 
1444284517 ONB2B3BB8 25.04.2021 4255;2187606199   3
```